# Use a class instance inside a module

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do this:

#### example_module.rb

```
module ExampleModule
   def example_method
     ...
     ExampleClass.new.do_something(arg_one, arg_two)
   end
end
```

#### example_class.rb

```
class ExampleClass
  def initialize()
    ...
  end
  def do_something(arg_first, arg_second)
    ...
  end
end
#>> Runtime error - uninitialized constant ExampleModule::ExampleClass
```

Is it possible to use a class instance inside a module? I found examples that do the opposite; they use a module to extend a class. What am I missing? Is there an article that explains this better?

Comment: Does `example_module.rb` have a `require` statement for `example_class`? e.g. something like `require_relative "example_class"`.

Comment: If you add a require `require './example_class'` (and remove or comment out the ellipsis) it works. But, it isn't really clear what you want to achieve; can you elaborate?

Comment: @engineersmnky That worked! Thank you. I wish i could mark it as my required answer. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @xrd true. Require relative worked for me better, but i guess that's just syntactic sugar. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TuringCreep glad it helped although `require_relative` is not just syntactic sugar for `require './xxx'`. `require_relative` will use the path of the file it is called from but `require './xxxx'` will use the current working directory which may or may not be the directory where the files are contained. I would always recommend the former over the latter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on top of your `example_module.rb` file.

`require ./example_class'`

Comment: `require_relative` worked, but i guess i was missing the concept of class inclusion and how it's done. Thanks for the answer.